# About max-width in IE6

Tags: internet-explorer-6, css

1. Is it possible to implement this in IE6?
2. If possible,how?

Answer (score 2):

You can use Javascript to get the viewports width and calculate the position as described here: http://www.svendtofte.com/code/max_width_in_ie/

```
<style>
p {
border:1px solid red;
width:expression( 
    document.body.clientWidth > (500/12) * 
    parseInt(document.body.currentStyle.fontSize)?
        "30em":
        "auto" );
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Uses conditional comments to enable this only for IE6
- Restricts element with id container to a max width of 850px.

CSS:

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
<style type="text/css">
img.img {
    width:expression(document.body.clientWidth > 640 ? "640px": "auto")
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: I'm not trying to limit the viewport,but an img.img {
max-width:640px;
}

Comment: ? So what. Then just change the css selector

Comment: Before considering a CSS expression, have a look at http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#css_expressions.